# the_title not working

Tags: custom-post-types, get-the-title

I'm using `the_title()` to show the title of a custom post type, but it's not working; the title does not show.

```
get_header();
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query -> query('post_type=press&showposts=20');
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : 
    $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="press-item">
        <div class="press-img"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium');?></div>
        <div class="press-content">
            <div class="press-title"><?php the_title(); ?> </div>
            <div class="press-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as your query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'press',
    'posts_per_page' => 20
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while // etc.
```

Also  you could try:

```
<div class="press-title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </div>
```